# chai-http not returning xml?

Tags: node.js, chai-http

I'm using **chai-http** to make requests in my tests. But when I set the **Accept** header to **application/xml**, suddenly the response body is just {}

Example test:

```
it('Should return eventlogs as xml', async() => {
const res = await chai.request(baseUrl).get(url).set('Accept', 'application/xml')
expect(res).to.have.status(200)
expect(res.body.toString()).to.include('<ArrayOfEventLog>')
})
```

```
expected '[object Object]' to include '<ArrayOfEventLog>'
```

Does chai-http not support xml?